# Structure of a dataframe, when whole dataframes are to be assigned to a class, for a Support Vector Machine

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, svm

I am facing a problem which I have not yet solved and I hope that one of you could help me.

I would like to create a support vector machine. So far I have many Excel files that I read into individual (pandas) dataframes. The Excel files all have seven columns. Each of these dataframes should be assigned to a certain class as a whole. Now I am not sure in which format I should build the training data and test data so that the algorithm assigns the dataframe as a whole to a class. I thought I would create a dataframe with eight columns. In the first seven columns, is in each row a column from a dataframe of an Excel file. And in the eighth column is the associated class.  And then hang the dataframes one after the other. Because as I understand it, the Support Vector Machine needs arguments of the type float() as input.
Is this the right idea at all?
And if so, does anyone have a tip on how I can implement this, because so far I'm failing.

Until now, I have read the individual columns from the Excel files into a list of dataframes. Then I made dataframes out of the lists and attached them to each other. Then I added the list of classes as another column.
Now I wanted to append all the dataframes together and an error occurs (see below).
Is this necessary at all?

```
dataframe_list_0 = [pd.read_excel(filepath + '\\' + file, usecols = [0]) for file in file_list]
dataframe_list_1 = [pd.read_excel(filepath + '\\' + file, usecols = [1]) for file in file_list]
dataframe_list_2 = [pd.read_excel(filepath + '\\' + file, usecols = [2]) for file in file_list]
dataframe_list_3 = [pd.read_excel(filepath + '\\' + file, usecols = [3]) for file in file_list]
dataframe_list_4 = [pd.read_excel(filepath + '\\' + file, usecols = [4]) for file in file_list]
dataframe_list_5 = [pd.read_excel(filepath + '\\' + file, usecols = [5]) for file in file_list]
dataframe_list_6 = [pd.read_excel(filepath + '\\' + file, usecols = [6]) for file in file_list]

dataframe_0 = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_list_0)
dataframe_1 = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_list_1)
dataframe_2 = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_list_2)
dataframe_3 = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_list_3)
dataframe_4 = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_list_4)
dataframe_5 = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_list_5)
dataframe_6 = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_list_6)

result = pd.concat([dataframe_0,dataframe_1,dataframe_2,dataframe_3, dataframe_4,dataframe_5,dataframe_6], axis =1)

result = pd.concat([result, maneuver], axis = 1)
result = pd.concat(result, axis = 0)

# This is the error i get when running the last line of code
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2632\3320468099.py in <module>
----> 1 result = pd.concat(result, axis = 0)
      2 # This is the Error i get when running the last line:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    345     ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: ['a']
    346     """
--> 347     op = _Concatenator(
    348         objs,
    349         axis=axis,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    380     ):
    381         if isinstance(objs, (ABCSeries, ABCDataFrame, str)):
--> 382             raise TypeError(
    383                 "first argument must be an iterable of pandas "
    384                 f'objects, you passed an object of type "{type(objs).__name__}"'

TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

Answer (score 0):

> And in the eighth column is the associated class.

As I read, your method is correct.

Regarding the error of:

```py
result = pd.concat([dataframe_0,dataframe_1,dataframe_2,dataframe_3, dataframe_4,dataframe_5,dataframe_6], axis =1)

result = pd.concat([result, maneuver], axis = 1)
result = pd.concat(result, axis = 0)
```

`pd.concat` first argument is a iterable of pandas dataframe, such as list (like your first line), tuple. When you concat them, it returns *a single new dataframe*.

Your second line is still correct, although I don't know what `maneuver` is.

However, that's why you see the error on the third line, because `result` now is a single dataframe.

To have what you need, here is the pseudocode:

```py
df1 = pd.read_excel(...)
df2 = pd.read_excel(...)
...

df1['class'] = 0  # assign class 0 to df1
df2['class'] = 1  # same business
...
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, ...], axis=0)
```

Then `df` is your final dataframe.